# How can i fix black screen when loading into the game on virtual machine?

Tags: gaming

I am trying to run a game on vmware workstation 16 player but black screen is appearing at the start (sound works tho). It works when the 3D accelerated card is not checked but then is laggy as hell (10fps). I can't passthrough the gpu because i don't have second one (only integrated one but i don't know if i can passthrough it). I tried sharing the gpu but i can't figure how, i know that it works on hyperV... I remember that it worked correctly once on vmware so i doubt that there are no solutions but i can't remember what i did to get it work.

game - Broken Ranks (game supports directx 11) 64 bits

my pc:
WINDOWS 10 pro 21H2
gtx 1050TI
intel core i5 7400
16GB ram
500gb ssd

virtual machine:
WINDOWS 10 pro 21H2
50gb disk
6gb ram
graphics

Also i have guest tools up to date. I have checked all:

Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI
Virtualize CPU performance counters
Virtualize IOMMU (IO memory management unit)
Accelerate 3D graphics

Comment: Does the game require DirectX or Vulkan? The current version of VMWare Workstation only supports specific versions of either of those APIs. Likewise, to my knowledge, you can't use VT-d with a GPU you are actively using by the host. You should [edit] your question to provide the necessary information to answer your question.

Comment: Try  3D acceleration with maximum memory in the video settings. This does not necessarily use all the physical memory but it help the VMware display hardware to work better. See if this works for you.

Comment: What informations do you need? Increasing to max memory doesn't work. Game uses directx 11.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you need to have realistic expectations. VMs aren't for gaming, period. That is unless you can add a 'real' GPU to it but even so you'll be using "inferior" hardware.

Comment: As i said, it worked before. I do not remember what did i do but it wasn't gpu passthrough for sure.

Comment: Can i maybe passthrough the integrated gpu?

Comment: @SukinSyn - You will be unable to do that.

Comment: The game works when i am disabling the VMware svga 3D but is lagging, why?

Comment: have you tried using hyper-v instead?

Comment: I am using VM for macro to do stuff on machine so i would be able to work on other stuff. So i tried hyperV, game worked but macro was bugged (I was leaving macro on hyperV on paint and it did work all the time but ingame after some time input didn't work).

Comment: I played other game (dead frontier) on machine and it worked well.